# Regex Python end words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Hello I have a python expression that works great, the more accurate regex accepts asterisks only at the end of words and () also..

```
^([A-Za-z0-9/_()*])+$
```

example i wish:

```
/path01* - OK
/path*01 - NO

/blog - OK
/blo*g - NO

/path() - OK
/pat()h - NO
```

for those who want to test.

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Confused, is there a question? Also, snippets are HTML, CSS, JavaScript, not python. Your regex is incorrectly formatted, missing closing bracket for character class `]`. Are multiple paths parts possible, e.g. `/path/blog()`? How about `/path()*` or `/path*()`?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for something like `^(?:/\w+)+(?:\(\)|\*)?$`

Comment: sorry, my English and a little bad.

This regex is in a script I did in python, That's the way you said and ideal.

Comment: `OK - path*` / `Not OK - pa*th`

Comment: if you enter the site regex101 and put the python option and add the regex `^([A-Za-z0-9/_()*])+$`  is ok, I just want that in this regex it does not match in * and () in the middle of words.

It can only be in the last charactere of the word.

Comment: You can use `^(?:/\w+)+(?:\(\)|\*)?$`

Comment: yes tried to use in regex online and gave error in the /

Error unescaped foward slash

Comment: You can change `/` to `\/` or, in some instances, change the regex delimiter from `/` to another symbol like `~`.

Comment: worked properly.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure if the leading `/` is required? But check this out: [`^(?:/?\w+)+(?:\(\)|\*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/z58hry/1)

Comment: `^(?:\w+)+(?:\(\)|\*)?$`  in this way it worked, correctly

Comment: more discovered a problem now he doesn't accept example

`força` and not even `home/blog`

Comment: Check out https://regex101.com/r/z58hry/3

Comment: did so and it worked, plus its and much more organized.
`^(?:\w+|ç|\/)+(?:\(\)|\ç|\/|\*)?$`

Comment: thanks, perfect man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and the comments below it, you're looking for the following regex:

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/z58hry/4); uses the `u` (`re.UNICODE`) flag.

```
^/?\w+(?:/\w+)*(?:\(\)|\*)?$
```

Explanation:

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `/?` Optionally match `/`
- `\w+` Match one or more word characters (since we added the Unicode flag, it'll also match characters like `ç`)
- `(?:/\w+)*` Match `/` followed by one or more word characters, any number of times
- `(?:\(\)|\*)?` Optionally match either `()` or `*` (literally)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

---

This properly matches:

```
/path01*
/blog
/path()
gfdsgdsf*
path*
força
home/blog
```

And properly fails to match:

```
/path*01
/blo*g
/path()h
pdsphgdh()*
```

Comment: Perfect...

so another doubt as i add also `home-path` and `login.css` with dash and dot

Comment: You can change `/` to `[/.-]`

Comment: `^/?\w+([.-]?\w+)\w+(?:/\w+)*(?:\(\)|\*)?$` ah ok, I did it that way, I'll follow your tip.